# Cant run ps1 script from out program files folder

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-sdk

I can run this script perfectly from my desktop:

```
    private void Sleep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
         ps.AddScript(@"D:\Desktop\alllightsoff.ps1");
         ps.Invoke();
    }
```

But when i change the paths to program files it does nothing.. any ideas?

```
    private void Sleep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        ps.AddScript(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Home Control\alllightsoff.ps1");
        ps.Invoke();
    }
```

Has proberly something to do with permissions, the script doesnt needs admin rights to run, and when i manually run the ps1 script from the program folder is just works ok.

I even tried %AppData% folder and getting the same result, ps1 file doesnt run.

Comment: So i found out that c:\test\ works and c:\te st\ not, so it has something to do with the spaces, i need to find some replacement code for spaces in c#

Comment: `AddScript` -> `AddCommand`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) has, as usual, provided the crucial pointer in a comment on the question:

- Use **[`.AddCommand()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addcommand?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0)** to add a ***command* by *name* or *executable / script-file path***.

  - In you needed to pass *arguments* to that command, you would then have to use the [`.AddParameters()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addparameters) method - see example below.
- By contrast, use the (poorly named) **[`.AddScript()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addscript?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0)** method to add **a self-contained piece of PowerShell *source code* as a *string***, which is parsed into a *script block* (a better name for the method would therefore have been `.AddScriptBlock()`).

  - In you needed to pass *arguments*, you would have to embed them directly in the source-code string - see example at the bottom.

Therefore, simply using `.AddCommand()` in lieu of `.AddScript()` is the solution:

```
ps.AddCommand(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Home Control\scripts\alllightsoff.ps1");
```

If you wanted to pass an *argument*, say `-Delay 60`, you'd then call:

```
ps.AddParameters(new Dictionary<string, int> { ["Delay"] = 60 });
```

---

#### Why `.AddScript()` didn't work:

Since you're passing a piece of PowerShell *source code*, the usual evaluation rules apply:

A file path with embedded spaces such as
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Home Control\alllightsoff.ps1` needs *quoting* for the PowerShell parser to recognize it as a *single* argument.

However, once quoted, you must use `&`,  the call operator, for PowerShell to know that the quoted path represents a *command* (script file) to *invoke* (otherwise, it would treat it as a *string*).

Hence, if you want to use `.AddScript()` in your case, you must use:

```
ps.AddScript(@"& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Home Control\scripts\alllightsoff.ps1'");
```

Note the leading `&`  and the `'...'` around the file path.

If you wanted to pass an *argument*, say `-Delay 60`, you'd have to include it in the string:

```
ps.AddScript(
  @"& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Home Control\scripts\alllightsoff.ps1' -Delay 60"
);
```