# How to pass parameter to a PowerShell script using C#?

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to execute a PowerShell script using `C#`

My script requires parameters to run otherwise, it'll throw an error.

Here is a stripped down version of my script

```
param ($url)
if ($url -eq $null) {
    throw "No Url was provided" 
}

write-host "$url was the provided value"
```

Now, using `C#` I am trying to execute the script as follow

```
try {
    var defaultSessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
    defaultSessionState.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted;

    using PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(defaultSessionState);

    ps.AddScript(@"d:\test.ps1");
    ps.AddParameter("url", "http://example.com/test/");
    ps.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("ErrorActionPreference", "stop");
} 
catch (Exception e) {

}
```

But I keep getting `No Url was provided` error. How can I correctly pass the parameter to my script, and how to access it?

Comment: Change `ps.AddScript("d:\test.ps1")` to `ps.AddCommand("d:\test.ps1")`

Comment: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addscript?view=pscore-6.2.0] addScript takes in a string and executes that... considers the script to be executable in powershell (not a file)

Answer (score 2):

`AddScript()` is for executing raw code - `D:\test.ps1` *happens* to be valid code, but it is more meant for dropping in a full self-contained script as a string.

You'll want to add the script file reference as a *command*, at which point we can apply parameters - for this, use `AddCommand()` instead:

```cs
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(defaultSessionState))
{
    ps.AddCommand("d:\test.ps1");
    ps.AddParameter("url", "http://example.com/test/");
    ps.AddParameter("ErrorAction", "Stop");
    // or
    ps.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("ErrorActionPreference", "stop");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61887432/45375) provides an effective solution, but let me expand on the explanation:

**The PowerShell SDK's [`.AddScript()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.AddScript) method** is somewhat poorly named in that it doesn't execute a script *file*, but an arbitrary *piece of PowerShell code*. That is, **it expects a string containing entire PowerShell *statements*, in other words: the *contents* of a script file - not the script file's *path*.**

Given that in PowerShell a piece of reusable code is represented as a script *block*, **something like `.AddScriptBlock()` would be a less confusing name** (though note that you must *not* enclose the string containing the statements to execute in `{ ... }` when you call `.AddScript()`).<sup>[1]</sup>

Mathias's answer shows how **[`.AddCommand()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.AddCommand) is the right method to use**, because a *command* in PowerShell is anything that represents something that can be directly executed: aliases, functions, cmdlets, external executables - and also *script files*.

---

As for **what you tried**:

String `d:\test.ps1` is interpreted *as a piece of PowerShell code* (the same way it would be if you submitted this string on the command line). That code happens to call a script file, but does so *without arguments*.
That is, your script was called, but without the parameter you added via `.AddParameter()`.

- Also note that if the script path happened to contain spaces or embedded variable references, you'd have to use *embedded* quoting and call the result via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-); e.g.,
  `.AddScript(@"& 'd:\test 1.ps1'");` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49211525/45375) to a closely related question for details.

However, note that your `.AddParameter()` call technically still worked, but it was the *script block as a whole* that received the parameter, not the (one) statement *inside it* - the call to `d:\test.ps1`.<sup>[2]</sup>

Technically, it would have been possible to *relay* the arguments to the script-file invocation, by way of [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) (in which all arguments are collected, in the absence of explicit parameter declarations via a `param(...)` block):

```
ps.AddScript(@"d:\test.ps1 @args");
```

That said, if all your code does is to invoke a single script file (with arguments), the `.AddCommand()` solution is both simpler and more efficient.

As an aside: `.AddScript()`, unlike `.AddCommand()`, is *not* subject to the executing machine's PowerShell [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies), assuming that the statements passed don't try to invoke script files; that is, statements composed only of expressions and commands other than script files (`*.ps1`) execute irrespective of what execution policy is in effect, though note that some modules automatically try to execute script files on import.

---

<sup>[1] `.AddScript("...")`, expressed in PowerShell code, effectively does the following:

`. { ... }`

That is, it parses the string as a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks), and executes it via `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) (when `.Invoke()` is later called).</sup>

<sup>[2] As stated, what you pass to `.AddScript()` is parsed into a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks), and script blocks - like functions and script files - can accept arguments, both *positionally* via the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) and - with explicitly declared parameters via a `param(...)` block - *named*. To use a simple example: `.AddScript('Write-Output $args[0]').AddArgument('foo')` is the equivalent of `. { Write-Output $args[0] } 'foo'`</sup>

Comment: Great answer. Passing parameters to a script, is it a feature that we can rely on? Or does it just happen to work? Can you point to the documentation for this feature? I really want to use it, but I am afraid it might break in the future.

Comment: Thanks, @MonticolaExplorator. Yes, you can rely on this feature. Please see the second footnote I've just added to the answer.