# PowerShell Object returns null

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-module, powershell-sdk

I have below command and it returns me null object . When I run the command separately in PowerShell window I get the right result. Below is my PowerShell method which is calling the command and the also the PowerShell command which I have defined. I am basically looking to return a string value. Please let me know what wrong am I doing?

C# method:

```
     public string RunScript( string contentScript, Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> parameters)
            {
                List<string> parameterList = new List<string>();
                foreach( var item in parameters )
                {
                    parameterList.Add( item.Value.ToString() );
                }
               
                using( PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create() )
                {
                    ps.AddScript( contentScript );
// in ContentScript I get "Get-RowAndPartitionKey" on debugging
                    ps.AddParameters( parameterList );//I get list of strings
                   
                    IAsyncResult async = ps.BeginInvoke();
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach( PSObject result in ps.EndInvoke( async ) )
// here i get result empty in ps.EndInvoke(async)
                    {
                        stringBuilder.AppendLine( result.ToString() );
                    }
                    return stringBuilder.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

My Powershell `GetRowAndPartitionKey` cmdlet definition, which the code above is trying to call:

```
public abstract class GetRowAndPartitionKey : PSCmdlet
    {
        [Parameter]
        public List<string> Properties { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    }

    [Cmdlet( VerbsCommon.Get, "RowAndPartitionKey" )]
    public class GetRowAndPartitionKeyCmd : GetRowAndPartitionKey

    {
        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            string rowKey = string.Join( "_", Properties );
            string pKey = string.Empty;
            
            WriteObject( new
            {
                RowKey = rowKey,
                PartitionKey = pKey
            } );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `EntityProperty`, and is `ps.HadErrors`=`true` after `Invoke()`?

Comment: EntityProperty is Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.EntityProperty. I havent checked ps.HadErrors.

Comment: just checked its false after BeginInvoke()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the PowerShell SDK, **if you want to pass parameters to a *single command*** with `.AddParameter()` / `.AddParameters()` / `AddArgument()`, **use [`.AddCommand()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.AddCommand), not `.AddScript()`**

[`.AddScript()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.AddScript) is for passing arbitrary pieces of *PowerShell code* that is executed as a *script block* to which the parameters added with `.AddParameters()` are passed.

That is, your invocation is equivalent to `& { Get-RowAndPartitionKey } <your-parameters>`, and as you can see, your `Get-RowAndPartitionKey` command therefore doesn't receive the parameter values.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61893812/45375) or more information.

---

Note: As a **prerequisite for calling your custom `Get-RowAndPartitionKey` cmdlet, you may have to explicitly *import the module (DLL)* that contains it**, which you can do:

- either: with a separate, synchronous `Import-Module` call executed *beforehand* (for simplicity, I'm using `.AddArgument()` here, with passes an argument *positionally*, which binds to the `-Name` parameter (which also accepts *paths*)):

  ```
  ps.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddArgument(@"<your-module-path-here>").Invoke();
  ```
- or: as part of a single (in this case asynchronous) invocation - note the required `.AddStatement()` call to separate the two commands:

  ```
  IAsyncResult async = 
    ps.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddArgument(@"<your-module-path-here>")
      .AddStatement()
        .AddCommand("GetRowAndPartitionKey").AddParameter("Properties", parameterList)
            .BeginInvoke();
  ```

`"<your-module-path-here>"` refers to the full file-system path of the module that contains the `Get-RowAndPartitionKey` cmdlet; depending on how that module is implemented, it is either a path to the module's *directory*, its `.psd1` module manifest, or to its `.dll`, if it is a stand-alone assembly.

**Alternative import method, using the  PowerShell SDK's dedicated [`.ImportPSModule()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.initialsessionstate.importpsmodule#System_Management_Automation_Runspaces_InitialSessionState_ImportPSModule_System_String___) method**:

This method obviates the need for an in-session `Import-Module` call, but requires extra setup:

- Create a default session state.
- Call `.ImportPSModule()` on it to import the module.
- Pass this session state to `PowerShell.Create()`

```
var iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
iss.ImportPSModule(new string[] { @"<your-module-path-here>" });
var ps = PowerShell.Create(iss);

// Now the PowerShell commands submitted to the `ps` instance
// will see the module's exported commands.
```

**Caveat**: A `PowerShell` instance reflects its initial session state in `.Runspace.InitialSessionState`, but as a conceptually *read-only* property; the tricky part is that it is *technically* still modifiable, so that mistaken attempts to modify it are *quietly ignored* rather than resulting in exceptions.

---

To **troubleshoot** these calls:

- Check `ps.HadErrors` after `.Invoke()` / `.EndInvoke()` to see if the PowerShell commands reported any (non-terminating) errors.
- Enumerate `ps.Streams.Errors` to inspect the specific errors that occurred.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66293994/45375) to a follow-up question for self-contained sample code that demonstrates these techniques.