# Powershell command not recognized when calling from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-module, powershell-sdk

This is in continuation to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66280000/powershell-object-returns-null/66280138?noredirect=1#comment117186600_66280138) here, I have a PowerShell command which I have created and am able to call the command in a PowerShell window, but when trying to call from C# method, I am getting error as the cmdlet is not recognized, I tried with other existing commands and get same error, so I suspect issue in Importing the Module, though I don't get that error in streams. Error. The only error I get is "Get-RowAndPartitionKey is not a recognized cmndlt, please check the spelling.....".

Would like to know if there is any other way, I should try it or if I can debug more here to see if my Module fetches all command or not. right now I am clueless how to fix this.

```
 public string RunScript( string contentScript, Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> parameters )
    {
        List<string> parameterList = new List<string>();
        foreach( var item in parameters )
        {
            parameterList.Add( item.Value.ToString() );
        }
        using( PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create() )
                       
        {
            IAsyncResult async =
             ps.AddCommand( "Import-Module" ).AddArgument( @"C:\Users\...\.D.PowerShell.dll" )
               .AddStatement()
               .AddCommand( "Get-RowAndPartitionKey" ).AddParameter( "Properties", "test" )
               .BeginInvoke();

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach( PSObject result in ps.EndInvoke( async ) )
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine( result.ToString() );
            }
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Below method do not return any error in Streams.Error or Verbose but no output also:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> RunScript( string scriptContents, List<string> scriptParameters )
        {
            // create a new hosted PowerShell instance using the default runspace.
            // wrap in a using statement to ensure resources are cleaned up.

            using( PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create() )
            {
                // specify the script code to run.
                ps.AddScript( scriptContents );

                // specify the parameters to pass into the script.
                ps.AddParameter( "Properties" ,"test") ;

                // execute the script and await the result.
                var pipelineObjects = await ps.InvokeAsync().ConfigureAwait( false );                
                return pipelineObjects;
            }
        }
```

scriptContent

```
 "\"$path = 'C:\\Users...\\.TabularData.PowerShell.dll'\\r\\nImport-Module $path\\r\\nGet-RowAndPartitionKeys\""
```

Comment: As for the second snippet: For the parameters to be passed to `Get-RowAndPartitionKey` (note that you've used the _singular_ form - no `s` at the the end - in the first snippet, so I'm using that here too, along with a verbatim string so you don't have to escape `"` chars.), you must pass it `@args`: `ps.AddScript(@"Import-Module ""C:\Users...\.TabularData.PowerShell.dll""; Get-RowAndPartitionKey @args")`

Comment: However, there is no benefit to bringing further variables into the mix: if you can't get your original snippet to work, the second one won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The following is **self-contained *PowerShell* sample code** that **uses on-demand compilation of C# code**:

- It shows that **the approach works in principle**, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66280138/45375) to your original question.

  - **Prerequisites**: The [PowerShell SDK package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63316570/45375) and .NET runtime used in the C# project that calls your custom `Get-RowAndPartitionKey"` cmdlet must be compatible with the PowerShell SDK and .NET runtime that you used to compile the assembly DLL that houses that cmdlet, to be imported via `Import-Module`.
  - The sample code below ensures that implicitly, by running directly from PowerShell, using the [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) cmdlet to compile C# code on demand - it works in Windows PowerShell as well as in PowerShell (Core) 7+.

    - In practice I've found that a .NET Framework-compiled DLL (from Windows PowerShell) also works in PowerShell (Core) (.NET (Core) 5.0), but not vice versa.
- It **shows troubleshooting techniques**, namely:

  - Adding the `-Verbose` switch to the `Import-Module` call to produce verbose output that lists the commands being imported from the given module (DLL).
  - Printing these verbose messages (look for `// --- TROUBLESHOOTING CODE`)
  - Printing any non-terminating PowerShell errors that occurred (as opposed to *exceptions* that you'd have to handle in C# code).

```sh
# Create a (temporary) assembly containing cmdlet "Get-RowAndPartitionKey".
# This assembly can directly be imported as a module from PowerShell.
# The cmdlet simply outputs "Hi from Get-RowAndPartitionKey" and
# echoes the elements of the list passed to -Properties, one by one.
$tempModuleDll = Join-Path ([IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) "TempModule_$PID.dll"
Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore $tempModuleDll
Add-Type @'
  using System.Management.Automation;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  [Cmdlet("Get", "RowAndPartitionKey")]
  public class GetRowAndPartitionKeyCmdlet : PSCmdlet {
    [Parameter] public List<string> Properties { get; set; }
    protected override void ProcessRecord() {
      WriteObject("Hi from Get-RowAndPartitionKey: ");
      WriteObject(Properties, true);
    }
  }
'@ -ErrorAction Stop -OutputAssembly $tempModuleDll

# Compile a C# class ad hoc to simulate your project, and call its static
# method, which imports the module and effectively calls 
#   Get-RowAndPartitionKey -Properties "foo", "bar"
(Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Management.Automation;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Text;

  public static class Foo {
    public static string RunScript(List<string> parameterList)
    {
      using (System.Management.Automation.PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
      {
        IAsyncResult async =
          // Add -Verbose to the Import-Module call, so that the list of 
          // commands being imported is written to the verbose output stream.
          ps.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddArgument(@"$tempModuleDll").AddParameter("Verbose", true)
            .AddStatement()
            .AddCommand("Get-RowAndPartitionKey").AddParameter("Properties", parameterList)
            .BeginInvoke();

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject result in ps.EndInvoke(async))
        {
          stringBuilder.AppendLine(result.ToString());
        }
        
        // --- TROUBLESHOOTING CODE

        // Print verbose output from the Import-Module call
        foreach (var v in ps.Streams.Verbose) { Console.WriteLine("VERBOSE: " + v.ToString()); }

        // Print any errors.
        foreach (var e in ps.Streams.Error) { Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.ToString()); }

        // ---

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
      }
    }
  }
"@ -ErrorAction Stop -PassThru)::RunScript(("foo", "bar"))

# Clean-up instructions:
if ($env:OS -eq 'Windows_NT') {
  Write-Verbose -vb "NOTE: Re-running this code requires you to start a NEW SESSION."
  Write-Verbose -vb "After exiting this session, you can delete the temporary module DLL(s) with:`n`n  Remove-Item $($tempModuleDll -replace '_.+', '_*.dll')`n "
} else {
  Write-Verbose -vb "NOTE: Re-running this code after modifying the embedded C# code requires you to start a NEW SESSION."
  Remove-Item $tempModuleDll
}
```

---

On my Windows 10 machine, both from PowerShell (Core) 7.0.5 and Windows PowerShell 5.1, the above yields (clean-up instructions omitted) the following, showing that everything worked as intended:

```sh
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\Temp\TempModule_11876.dll'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Get-RowAndPartitionKey'.
Hi from Get-RowAndPartitionKey:
foo
bar
```

Specifically, line `VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Get-RowAndPartitionKey'.` indicates that the custom cmdlet was successfully imported into the session.

Comment: Are these two library package have different roles: PowerShellStandard.Library and Microsft. Powershell.SDK. I see in my earlier there was PowerShellStandardLibrary 5.1.1 available but now its not there in nuget package manager

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint, yes, the former comprises just _reference assemblies_ that at runtime rely on a regular PowerShell installation; the latter comprises the assemblies for fully hosting PowerShell (Core) as part of the application. As stated, before use one _or_ the other: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63316570/45375) (also linked to from the answer).

Comment: Also I posted another Question, making the command as simple as possible ..maybe you can look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66313904/whats-the-correct-way-to-get-output-for-this-powershell-in-c-sharp