# Whats the correct way to get output for this Powershell in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-module, powershell-sdk

I am not getting any error below but I am also not getting the output. Below is the Powershell cmd and the C# method which is calling it. I would like to know if it is written correctly and how can I get the output as coming from powershell. It works fine when I run from PowerShell window

Pwsh cmd:

```
public class GetRowAndPartitionKeys : Cmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(Mandatory = false)]
        public List<string> Properties { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    }

    [Cmdlet( VerbsCommon.Get, "RowAndPartitionKeys" )]
    public class GetRowAndPartitionKeyCmd : GetRowAndPartitionKeys

    {
        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {            
            WriteObject ("Hi");
        }
    }

}
```

C# method:

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> RunScript(  )
        {
            // create a new hosted PowerShell instance using the default runspace.
            // wrap in a using statement to ensure resources are cleaned up.
           string scriptContents = "Import-Module 'C:\Users\...\Powershell.dll";
            using( PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create() )
            {
                // specify the script code to run.
            ps.AddScript( scriptContents ).AddCommand( "Get-RowAndPartitionKeys" );


            // execute the script and await the result.
            var pipelineObjects = await ps.InvokeAsync().ConfigureAwait( false );
           
            foreach( var item in pipelineObjects )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( item.BaseObject.ToString() );
            }
            return pipelineObjects;
        }
```

Comment: Capture the output : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershellstreams-2?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0

Comment: this one for C++ mine is C#

Comment: Why do you think it is c++?  The top of page says c#.

Comment: the one you sent shows c++ but i changed to c# but I am not sure how to use it, can you tell me in my current method, where and how should i insert

Comment: Try look at main page.  You simply need to get the stream : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0

Comment: i m not getting you, what should i capture, if i am not getting anything

Comment: I found following : Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (PSObject obj in results)
                {
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
                }

Comment: did that, it comes out after psInvoke()

Comment: Found it here : https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/6y7b2g/capture_powershell_output_in_c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66293994/45375), the following **self-contained sample code demonstrates that the approach works *in principle***, after correcting the following problems in your code:

- An `.AddStatement()` call is missing between the `.AddScript()` and the `.AddCommand()` call; this is necessary for the (script block-based) `Import-Module` call and the `Get-RowAndPartitionKeys` call to be treated as *separate statements*.
- Pseudo-code line `string scriptContents = "Import-Module 'C:\Users\...\Powershell.dll";` is missing a closing `'` (possibly just an artifact of posting here).
- Also, troubleshooting code is added below.

While the orchestration code is in PowerShell, **actual C# projects, compiled via the [.NET SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download)** are used, in combination with version `7.1.2` of the **PowerShell (Core) SDK package, [`Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK/)**.

**After running the code, which creates and runs the test projects, you can inspect and experiment with them yourself**  (`./module` is the project for the module DLL that defines the `Get-RowAndPartitionKeys` cmdlet, `./app` is the project for the application that calls it):

```sh
$tmpDir = (New-Item -Force -Type Directory (Join-Path temp: $PID)).FullName

$tmpModuleDir = (New-Item -Force -Type Directory (Join-Path $tmpDir module)).FullName
$tmpAppDir = (New-Item -Force -Type Directory (Join-Path $tmpDir app)).FullName
$tmpPublishDir = (New-Item -Force -Type Directory (Join-Path $tmpDir publish)).FullName

$tmpModuleDll = Join-Path $tmpPublishDir module.dll

Push-Location

# ---

Write-Verbose -vb "Creating module DLL with sample cmdlet..."

Set-Location $tmpModuleDir

dotnet new classlib --force >$null || $(exit $LASTEXITCODE)

dotnet add package Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK >$null || $(exit $LASTEXITCODE)

@'
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace demo {
    public class GetRowAndPartitionKeys : Cmdlet 
    {
      public List<string> Properties { get; set; }
    }
    
    [Cmdlet( VerbsCommon.Get, "RowAndPartitionKeys" )]
    public class GetRowAndPartitionKeyCmd : GetRowAndPartitionKeys
    {
      protected override void ProcessRecord()
      {
          WriteObject ("Hi");
      }
    }
}
'@ | Set-Content Class1.cs

dotnet publish -o $tmpPublishDir >$null || $(exit $LASTEXITCODE)

# ---

Write-Verbose -vb "Creating console application that imports the module DLL and calls the sample cmdlet..."
Set-Location $tmpAppDir

dotnet new console --force >$null  || $(exit $LASTEXITCODE)

dotnet add package Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK >$null || $(exit $LASTEXITCODE)

@"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace demo {

    public static class App {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var unused = new Foo().RunScript().Result;
        }
    }    

    public class Foo {
        public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> RunScript()
        {
            string scriptContents = @"Import-Module -Verbose ""$tmpModuleDll""";
            using(PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.AddScript(scriptContents).AddStatement().AddCommand("Get-RowAndPartitionKeys");
                var pipelineObjects = await ps.InvokeAsync().ConfigureAwait( false );
                
                // --- TROUBLESHOOTING CODE

                // Print verbose output from the Import-Module call
                foreach (var v in ps.Streams.Verbose) { Console.WriteLine("VERBOSE: " + v.ToString()); }
        
                // Print any errors.
                foreach (var e in ps.Streams.Error) { Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.ToString()); }
        
                // ---                

                foreach (var item in pipelineObjects)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.BaseObject.ToString());
                }

                return pipelineObjects;
            }
        }
    }
}
"@ | Set-Content Program.cs

# ---

Write-Verbose -vb "Compiling and invoking the console application..."
dotnet run 

Pop-Location

Write-Verbose -vb @"
The test projects are located in $tmpDir.
To clean up, run:

   Remove-Item "$tmpdir" -Recurse
 
"@
```

On my Windows 10 machine (running from PowerShell 7.1.2), I get:

[image: results]

As you can see:

- the verbose output confirms that the cmdlet was properly imported
- the `Hi` shows that the cmdlet was successfully called.