# PrincipalSource Property is blank in Get-LocalGroupMember by PowerShell Script

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am getting "**PrincipalSource**" property Blank while running following command by PowerShell Script in c#.

**Command :** Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators

PowerShell Output:
[image]

By C# Code passing Script path:

[image]

I have written output in text file.

Script is executing by c# Code because I can see output but PrincipalSource value blank.

**System details:**

Windows 10,
PowerShell 5.1,
.Net Version 4.8

**Sample Code:**

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();

powershell.Runspace = runspace 
powershell.AddScript(scriptPath);
powershell.Runspace.Open();
powershell.Invoke();

powershell.Runspace.Close();
powershell.Dispose();
```

==========================================================

```
        PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
        powershell.AddCommand("Get-LocalGroupMember");
        powershell.AddParameter("Name", "Administrators");

       
        Collection <PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke(); ;
       
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject obj in results)
        {
           
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-20}{1}",
            obj.Members["ObjectClass"].Value,
            obj.Members["Name"].Value,
            obj.Members["PrincipalSource"].Value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("End");
```

[image]

Comment: Curious symptom; I have no explanation, but as an aside: Somewhat confusingly, the purpose of the `.AddScript()` PowerShell SDK method is to pass a _string_ containing _arbitrary PowerShell code_, whereas it is usually better to use `.AddCommand()` to invoke a _script file_ (`*.ps1`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49211525/45375) for details.

Comment: I would like to run different script every time so passing script name as argument and each script has multiple lines of code.

Comment: Right, so it should be `powershell.AddCommand(scriptPath)` (use, e.g., `.AddParameters()`  to pass arguments to the script). (But, again, this is just an aside, and won't solve your problem.)

Comment: Tried with powershell.AddCommand(scriptPath) .AddParameters()

Still Getting PrincipalSource empty

Comment: That was to be expected (as I said, this was an _aside_, and wouldn't solve your problem. It would, however, prevent problems if your script path contained spaces.)

Comment: I've seen problems like yours if the property in question is a _script_ property, but that is not the case here. Still, I wonder what happens if you use `Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators | Select-Object -Property *` - you'll lose the original type identity, but you should get - static - copies of the original property values.

Comment: They're using [LsaLookupUserAccountType](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts/LocalAccounts/Native.cs#L419C21-L421) to determine the principal source: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts/LocalAccounts/Sam.cs#L3026-L3078. You could easily implement the same logic yourself